# Elasticsearch. Can not find custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have model like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(indexName = "indexName", type = "typeName")
@Setting(settingPath = "/elastic/elastic-setting.json")
public class Model extends BaseModel {
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, analyzer = "customAnalyzer")
    private String name;
}
```

And i have elastic-setting.json inside ../resources/elastic/elastic-setting.json:

```
{
   "index": {
   "number_of_shards": "1",
   "number_of_replicas": "0",
   "analysis": {
     "analyzer": {
       "customAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I clean my elastic DB and when i start my application i have exception:

```
MapperParsingException[analyzer [customAnalyzer] not found for field [name]]
```

What's wrong with my code?
Help me, please!

**EDIT**

**Val**, I thought @Setting is like an addition for @Document, but looks like they are interchangeably.
In my case i also have another model, with:

```
@Document(indexName = "indexName", type = "anotherTypeName")
```

So, first i create index with name "indexName" for anotherModel, next when elastic preparing Model, it see, that index with name "indexName" already created, and he does not use @Setting.

Now i have another quesion.
How to add custom analyzer to already created index in java code, for example in InitializingBean. Something like - is my analyzer created? no - create. yes - do not create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `elastic-setting.json` file like this:

```
{
   "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "0"
   },
   "analysis": {
     "analyzer": {
       "customAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to delete your index first and recreate it.

**UPDATE**

You can certainly add a custom analyzer via Java code, however, you won't be able to change your existing mapping in order to use that analyzer, so you're really better off wiping your index and recreating it from scratch with a proper `elastic-setting.json` JSON file.

Comment: I'm apologize, i have another problem at all. Look at my edit, please.

Answer (score 0):

For Val:
Yeah, i use something like this.
Previously, i had added @Setting in one of my entity class, but when i started app, index with same name was already created, before Spring Data had analysed entity with @Setting, and index was not modified, because index with same name was already created.

Now I add annotation @Setting(path = "elastic-setting.json") on abstract baseModel, and high level hierarchy class was scanned firstly and analyzer was created as well.